# Can Spring @Cacheable be configured to block on a cache miss?

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

Can the Spring `@Cacheable` be configure so that if there is a cache miss calls to the cacheable method get blocked until the cacheable method executes once and the cache is populated?

In my case I am dealing with data from the db that does not change often in fact if this data changes then the app will need to be restarted. I can create `@PostConstruct` methods and init the data as each service is launching but that does not seem as "elegant" as the `@Cacheable` annotation.

I am planning to use EhCache with the Spring `@Cacheable` annotation.

**update:**

Here are some issues that I ran into in trying to use @PostConstruct, in case some one else run into those issues. `@PostConstruct` methods can't be `@Transactional` because they run after the properties of the object are set and not after the whole spring context is configured. So you can't assume that the TX manager is all setup and configured by the time `@PostConstruct` method is called. The workaround for this is to implement a `ApplicationListener` and inject a TransactionTemplate manually ... etc a lot of extra work that is simplified by using `@Cacheable`.

Comment: I added an ApplicationListener and configured it to listen for the ContextRefreshedEvent, but still the execution of my method at this time in the lifecycle is too soon for cacheable to work on my method. Could you elaborate on what else you'd need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `@PostConstruct` is inelegant, seems perfect solution to me. You want the method(s) called only when app is restarted. What could be better ?

But you can also do this to block calls until a cache is available

```
@Cacheable(cacheName="yourCache", decoratedCacheType= DecoratedCacheType.SELF_POPULATING_CACHE)
public List<String> getWhatever(int id) {
//call database
}
```

and to make the cache autorefresh this :

```
@Cacheable(cacheName="yourCache", refreshInterval=1000, decoratedCacheType= DecoratedCacheType.REFRESHING_SELF_POPULATING_CACHE)
public List<String> getWhatever(int id) {
  //call database
}
```

[kudos](http://cleancode.se/2012/03/31/refreshing-caches-in-ehcache.html)

Comment: ehcache and concurrentmap based cache are supported, but you can  yr own one in : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Comment: I am pretty sure @NimChimpsky is using the `ehcache-spring-annotations`, not the Spring annotations (the linked docs are therefore erroneous). If there is a way to do this using pure Spring, I'd like to hear about it. I've answered below with a cleaner solution using the `ehcache-spring-annotations` API.

Answer (score 2):

Support for synchronized caches has been added in Spring 4.3:

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "foos", sync = true)
    public Foo getFoo(String id) { ... }

}
```

See: https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3

Answer (score 1):

"block on concurrent miss" is supported directly by the (annoyingly same name of annotation) [`@Cacheable` from ehcache-spring-annotations](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/UsingCacheable). Just set `selfPopulating = true`.

The spring XML configuration is also a lot cleaner than using the Spring `@Cacheable`.

The biggest disadvantage is that you will be tied to ehcache and cannot wire other implementations (e.g. useful for unit testing).